# Rollback não funciona

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Então pessoal eu tenho uma transaction pra persistir diverso dados em tabelas diferentes no meu banco, se por um acaso um registro der errado eu preciso que ele de um rollback, afinal eu dependo do retorno de id de um para fazer persistência de outro, além disso não posso deixar que algumas tabelas sejam persistidas e outras não.
O problema é que meu rollback não esta funcionando, eu tenho alguns métodos, eles estão com uma Promise então se der erro ele da um reject e na minha visão ele cairia para o catch do método runQuery, ai ali tem um rollback e este rollback me faria desfazer as operações, o problema é que os erros não estão caindo ali, e no caso os erros que estou gerando são diversos só pra teste.

```
async run(data: any) {
try {
  const response = await this.runQuery(data);


  return 'response';
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}}

async runQuery(data: any) {
try{
  connection.beginTransaction();  

  data[2].post.Ordem_servico = await this.insertGenericReturn(data[0]);

  await this.insertEpisOrder(data[6], data[2].post.Ordem_servico);

  data[5].post.Equipamento_FK = await this.insertGenericReturn(data[2]);

  data[3].post.Ordem_Servico = data[2].post.Ordem_servico;

  data[5].post.Locais_FK = await this.insertGenericReturn(data[3]);

  let listOperations : any = await this.insertOperationsOrder(data[4]);


  for (const element of listOperations) {
    data[5].post.Operacao_FK = element;
    await this.insertGenericReturn(data[5]);
  }

  connection.commit();

  return { result: 'Ordem de serviço criada!' }
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err runTransaction :>> ', err);

  await connection.rollback();
  throw err;
}}

private async insertGenericReturn(data: any) {
try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(data.query, data.post,  async (err: any, result: any) =>{
      if (err) reject({ status: 401, msg: 'Não foi possível realizar a operação!', ...err })
      resolve(result.insertId);
    });
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}}

private async insertEpisOrder(data: any, order: any) {
try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < data.post.length; index++) {
      data.post[index].ordemServico_idOrdemServico = order;
    }
    for (const epi of data.post) {
      connection.query(data.query, epi, async (err: any, result: any) =>{
        if (err) reject({ status: 401, msg: 'Não foi possível realizar a operação!', ...err })
        resolve('EPIs cadastrados');
      });
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}}

private async insertOperationsOrder(data: any) {
try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let listOperations: any = [];
    let response: any;
    for (const item of data.post) {
      connection.query(data.query, item, async (err: any, result: any) =>{
        if (err) reject({ status: 401, msg: 'Não foi possível realizar a operação!', ...err })

        listOperations.push(result.insertId);

        resolve(listOperations);
      });
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do porque não estaria indo para meu rollback? tipo ele vai pra queles métodos de inserção mas não retorno pro catch do runQuery que tem o rollback, se puderem ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal eu resolvi aqui e vou compartilhar a resolução, talvez seja útil pra alguém:

Eu adicionei um tratamento no catch o método é este

```
private getQueryError(err: any): { status: number, err: string } {
const error = Object.assign({}, err);

if (_.has(error, 'code')) return { status: 400, err: 'Não foi possível concluir a operação!' };
if (error.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') return { status: 400, err: 'item já cadastrado!' };
return { status: 400, err: _.get(error, 'message', 'Não foi possível concluir a operação!') }}
```

E obviamente adicionei chamadas a este método no meu catch no caso:

```
const error = this.getQueryError(err);
```

Enfim espero que possa ajudar alguém que esteja tendo essa dificuldade ou que esteja trabalhando com transactions.